# Speclevel in Reverse

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have an expression involving several dot products, I give a simplified example:

```
expr={A.B,C.D}
```

I want to reverse all dot products, and try

```
expr/.Dot[x__]:> Reverse[Dot[x]]
```

which returns `{C.D,A.B}`, i.e., `Reverse` operates on the first level of expr, not of its argument. If I write

```
Reverse[Dot[x],2]
```

in the command above I do get the desired `{B.A,D.C}`, i.e., now `Reverse` operates on the second level of expr. This only works because all dot products in expr are at the same level, which is not the case in my original problem.

I have two questions:

1. How to explain the above behavior of Reverse?
2. How to accomplish the reversal of the order of the dot products when scattered at various levels within an expression?

Comment: Patter matching comes to the rescue: `{{{a . b}}, {c . d}} /. Dot[x_, y_] -> Dot[y, x]`

Comment: The problem is that `Dot[x__]` evaluates to `x__`. You need to use `HoldPattern` to prevent this, although @lericr's answer is much cleaner.

Comment: Many thanks to @lericr and @carlwoll for the answer, and to @ben for formatting the question. The suggestion by @danielhuber works for two arguments in `Dot` (or a given fixed number), which is not the case in my problem (I get dot products of various numbers of arguments) - I guess one could always write a list of substitutions for two, three, etc arguments.

Comment: @ChryssomalisChryssomalakos Try with MapAt[Reverse, tensor, level]. Put level = {All} when ``TensorRank[tensor] = 1``, level={All, All} when ``TensorRank[tensor] = 2`` and so on. You can build a function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll provide a solution, second I'll explain the results you got.

1. The better solution is to match on the expression that you want to reverse:

   `expr /. dot_Dot :> Reverse[dot]`

   This will do the replacement at every level in the expression.

====

original explanation is wrong

2. Why did your original attempt behave so strangely? The left side or your rule was `Dot[x__]`, and what that means is "find all expressions, one or more elements long, that find themselves inside a Dot-headed expression, and name them 'x'". Well, all of A, B, C, and D match that pattern. And preserving their relative structure, what the replacement rule did was generate

   `Reverse[Dot[{A . B, C . D}]]`

   Because of the semantics of Dot, this is just

   `Reverse[{A . B, C . D}]`

   and you can see where it went from there.

====

[Edit based on Carl Woll's comment: Yeah, the Dot[x__] is actually evaluated, so your rule is actually `x__ :> Reverse[Dot[x]]`]

2. Why did your original attempt behave so strangely? The left side or your rule was `Dot[x__]`, which evaluates to just `x__`, and so your rule matches the entire expression. et cetera

Comment: Your point 2 is confusing. The issue is just that `Dot[x__]` evaluates to `x__`

Comment: yep. that was lame. I was thinking it was pattern matching on the head (but that would have been _Dot). I should have just used Trace to see what was going on rather than tie myself up in pattern matching knots.